# Firebase app distribution icon does not get updated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-app-distribution, launcher-icon

I am trying to update the Firebase app distribution logo. After uploading my client App to Firebase, the logo remains as a basic avatar image, that is, if the App is called "Excellent", the logo reflects a green background with an E in the middle. There is no much info out there about this topic. They say uploading a new version with the launcher fixes it, but I have done that multiple times and nothing. The default avatar logo prevails.

I cannot upload any code in here since it is not my app, but the question is if you guys know of any possible ways to fix this, or any pointers that I may have overlooked.

I created the logo following Android Studio... New-> Image Asset, etc... the launchers are all created fine, but the icon in App Distribution in Firebase never updates.

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Did you fix this issue? And if you did how please I have the same issue

Comment: @Cj_Rodriguez not yet... it is frustrating, nobody seems to know :(

Comment: I emailed support, and they replied that I should delete the project and re-add it. On this site, you can also get an idea of the outages. The same issue happened on the 9th March. https://status.firebase.google.com/products/jJL4tksewGpGpbQpuuYb/history

Comment: Im experiencing this issue on an old app, where the logo has been changed.

Comment: Still no real solution for this. I don´t understand why Firebase does not have the choice of adding an icon inside the app distribution. IN my case, it has happened again, another app with a weird icon, nothing to do with the launcher icon inside the app....